# In Node.js, how to prevent the client from opening more than one instance from my web site

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running my server in node.js language and i am using express module, how can i prevent the client from opening more than one instance of my web site

Comment: There isn't really a good way to do this without authentication. Do you require authentication?

Comment: @TimothyStrimple yes, i require authentication, but how that will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to handle making sure only one authenticated socket per user is allowed at a time.

```
var socketSessions = {};

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  var request = {
    url: socket.request.url,
    headers: {
      cookie: socket.request.headers.cookie
    }
  }

  cookieParser(request, {}, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    expressSession(sessionSettings)(request, {}, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      socket.session = request.session;
      if(socketSessions[request.session.userId]) {
        var oldSocket = socketSessions[request.session.userId];
        oldSocket.disconnect();
      }

      socketSessions[request.session.userId] = socket;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Assumptions for the code above:
1. You're using Express.
2. You're using cookie-parser and express-session.
3. your authentication mechanism creates a session.userId

This creates a socket.io middleware which maps a session to a socket. If a new socket connection comes in for a user, we disconnect the other socket, and then create a new socket/session map.

Comment: my goal is to make sure that the number of connections to server equal the number connected machines, so 100 connections means 100 machines

Comment: That's not normally how the web works. Unless you're doing a lot of ajaxy stuff, refreshing a page 10 times is the same as opening the website in 10 tabs. What exactly is the goal, minimizing bandwidth usage?

Comment: yes, that's one of the goals, because my web site is expected to have more than 10,000 users, each user will be connected to server using socket.io , guess what will happen if each user opened double instances then i have to serve 20,000 but actually i only paid from 10,000

Comment: Also, some users will try to open many connections, i want to prevent those actions

Comment: So you don't need to prevent them from opening multiple instances necessarily, you just need to prevent multiple instances of socket.io connections?

Comment: Updated the answer. A new socket connection will disconnect the old socket connection ensuring only one socket.io connection is open at a time.

Comment: if user open new instance in incognito window then the server will not be aware from the old session

Comment: They won't be aware of the old session, but the logged in user's userId will be the same. `if(socketSessions[request.session.userId])` You'll notice the socket is actually tied to a userId, not the sessionId.

Answer (score 2):

Since most server-side techniques don't scale because they require you to hold state server-side, I'd go with a client-side approach. You could communicate between windows using cookies, and make sure only one client "owns" the cookie at any given time. Maybe use something like the [Raft Consensus Algorithm](http://raftconsensus.github.io/) to pick which window is the active one, then have the other display "Multiple sessions not allowed."

Comment: What about the case the user use incognito windows?

Comment: @AkramKamalQassas Or different browsers. If it *has* to be one session, the only way is server-side. I'd just tend to avoid it, but you can use the technique as long as there's a way to communicate between browsers.